# Why can't I iterate through object in get_queryset?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

If i use Station.objects.last() in get_queryset method i will get an error `TypeError at /data-show/ 'Station' object is not iterable`. Why is that and how can i fix it?

views.py

```
class ShowStationAndSensorsView(ListAPIView):
serializer_class = StationSerializer

def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = Station.objects.last()
    return queryset
```

serializers.py

```
class SensorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Sensor
        fields = '__all__'

def create(self, validated_data):
    sensor_data = validated_data.pop('sensors')
    station = Station.objects.create(**validated_data)
    station.save()
    for sensor in sensor_data:
        s = Sensor.objects.create(**sensor)
        station.sensors.add(s.id)
    return station
```

Comment: `get_queryset` should return a `QuerySet`, not a single object.

Comment: This is a `ListAPIView` so I don't really understand why it would make sense to return a single object in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to iterate thorow a variable that its not iterable. Check the variable type with `print(type(Station.objects))`